# Javascript Object array sum in specific object position

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
let arr = [ { "Id": 0, "Name": "Product 1", "Price": 10 }, 
            { "Id": 0, "Name": "Product 1", "Price": 15 } ]
```

How can i sum `1` in all `Price` positions to be like:

```
let Final_arr = [ { "Id": 0, "Name": "Product 1", "Price": 11 }, 
                  { "Id": 0, "Name": "Product 1", "Price": 16 } ]
```

Thanks! ;)

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I tried to use `map` and `reduce`, but i'm not getting what i expected :(

Comment: let finalArr = arr.map(item => ({ ...item, "Price": item["Price"] + 1}))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

loop through the array and increment the `price` :
keep in mind that this will mutate the original array, 
use `arr.slice(0).forEach( ...`  to keep the original as is.

```js
let arr = [{
    "Id": 0,
    "Name": "Product 1",
    "Price": 10
  },
  {
    "Id": 0,
    "Name": "Product 1",
    "Price": 15
  }
]

arr.forEach((e) => {
  return e.Price++
});

/*

const newArr = arr.slice(0).forEach((e) => {
  return e.Price++
});


*/
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: but this will return a numbers array instead of the original object structure with the modified price

Comment: @Efemorav run the snippet, you'll see that it returns the same original structure

Comment: This is a "bad" usage of `array.map`. This operates the same way as `array.forEach` since you're not mapping the array to return something.

Comment: @Phiter , agree, i guess i thought too quickly , i corrected the answer, thnx

Comment: First of all, thanks for answers! Very clear. I'd like to know why `array.map` is a bad idea if it works as same as `forEach`?

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a `for` loop:

```js
var arr = [{
    "Id": 0,
    "Name": "Product 1",
    "Price": 10
  },
  {
    "Id": 0,
    "Name": "Product 1",
    "Price": 15
  }
];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  arr[i].Price++;

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
arr.map((a) => { a.Price = a.Price + 1 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clone the array and map it to get a new one, like this:

```js
let arr = [ { "Id": 0, "Name": "Product 1", "Price": 10 }, 
            { "Id": 0, "Name": "Product 1", "Price": 15 } ];
            
let newArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr)).map(function(item){
  item.Price++;
  return item;
});


console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using es2015 syntax this could be achieved with:

```
const Final_arr = arr.map((item) => {
    return { ...item, price: item.Price + 1 };
});
```

Using vanilla JS, you could do like below:

```
var Final_arr = arr.map(function (item) {
    return { Id: item.Id, Name: item.Name, Price: item.Price + 1 };
});
```